# Display html tag values in IOS7 iphone

Tags: iphone, href

Hi I am developing small iPhone application. I am getting string from server like this

```
You can download the MyApp on the Google Play store:<a href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp' style='display:inline-block;padding:0px;margin-left:10px'>MyApp</a>",
```

I want to display it as normal string with MyApp text as link. How to do this. Is there any way to do this. 
Need Help. Thank you.

I tried this but still not working

```
NSAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                               initWithString:@“You can download the MyApp on the Google Play store:<a href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myapp' style='display:inline-block;padding:0px;margin-left:10px'>MyApp</a>"

                               attributes:[cell.answer.attributedText attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:NULL]];
cell.answer.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Comment: `NSAttributedString`? `UIWebView`?

Comment: I am using normal NSString and not displaying in webview. It is jus normal label.

Comment: `NSAttributedString` so.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with "just a normal label".

try to use `NSAttributedString` or put HTML code in a `UIWebView` then display it.

I would suggest you to take look at [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)

EDIT

with NSAttributedString

```
NSMutableAttributedString * appLabelString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"You can download the MyApp on the ...."];
[appLabelString addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: @"http://www.itunes.com" range: NSMakeRange(21, 26)];
appLabel.attributedText = appLabelString;
```

Comment: Hi kaiusee thank you for your quick replay. I don't want to use webview for this. Is there any other solution.

Comment: if you don't want webview (which i don't like to use all the time)  I would suggest you to take look at OHAttributedLabel. Read about what it can do here : https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel#about-these-classes

Comment: Yeah I checked it but it is deprecated since IOS6 I want to use it for IOS7 as well :(

Comment: @nilkash you might have to change the range based on your text, but this is just a sample

Comment: will try this solution and let you know if it working or not. But My scenario is like this I have many text like this. So have to take care of those positions manually. Is there no in build support to  display such text?